# R: Find vector elements containing multiple string matches

Tags: r, regex

I would like to find the elements of a vector (strings) which contain all of the strings specified by another vector. For example,

```
x <- c("xxxabcxdxexfxx", "xxaxbcdexx", "xaxxxbc")
a <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
```

I would like to find the elements of `x` that contain all the strings in `a`, so to get

```
[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sapply(x, function(string) all(Vectorize(grepl)(pattern = a, x = string)))
#xxxabcxdxexfxx     xxaxbcdexx        xaxxxbc 
#          TRUE          FALSE          FALSE
```

OR

```
rowSums(sapply(a, function(P) grepl(P, x))) == length(a)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

OR

```
grepl(pattern = paste(sort(a), collapse = ""),
      x = sapply(strsplit(x, ""),
                 function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "")))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

OR

```
lengths(sapply(strsplit(x,""), setdiff, x = a)) == 0
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Still got the shortest one ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Another one:

```
sapply(strsplit(x,""), function(y) all(a %in% y))
```

Comment: That works in this case, but I am guessing that it would not work if the strings I am looking for were more than one character long, right?

Comment: That's true, in that scenario using `grep` like in @d.b and @Henrik's solutions makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

Using `gregexpr`:

```
lengths(gregexpr(pattern = paste(a, collapse = "|"), text = x)) == length(a)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```